# Why use reverse nibbled ​in decimal-octets in SMS PDUs?

Tags: sms, pdu, smspdu

I am studying for SMS PDU.

However, I do not know why the SMS PDU transmits the phone number and the like by reverse nibbled. (012345 to 103254)

Why does it work like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noone knows excactly :)
But in telco within SS7 protocol, almost all numbers are reversed (vlr,hlr,imsi etc.)
In older days on slow networking, every bit matters, thats why SS7 is so optimized.
I believe it has to do with a speed when number has odd length.
In newer protocols (like Volte) there is no such thing anymore.